# Como mostrar el string del item seleccionado en un JComboBox almacenado desde una tabla de MySQL

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente problema, al seleccionar una fila de mi JTable para modificar sus datos, llamo a un formulario cuyo datos de la tabla se llenan en los campos del mismo, dentro del formulario hay un JCombobox que se llena con los datos almacenados de la tabla de mi BD, mi pregunta es, **COMO puedo mostrar el string de dicho id almacenado en la tabla de mi base de datos en el combo?** 
Porque obtengo el numero de id, o sea, me muestra el numero de id dentro del combo y lo que yo quiero que me muestre el string asociado a dicho id.

El combo es cargado de esta forma.

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel comboLocalidad() {
        DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerLocalidades = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_localidades()");
            ResultSet rs = obtenerLocalidades.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
                valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar auto completar busqueda:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return valor;
    }
```

La clase localidad.

```
public class Localidad{
    public int idlocalidad;
    public String localidad;

    public Localidad(int idlocalidad, String localidad) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public int getIdlocalidad() {
        return idlocalidad;
    }

    public void setIdlocalidad(int idlocalidad) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return localidad;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Localidad)) {
            return false;
        }
        Localidad localidad = (Localidad) obj;
        if (idlocalidad != localidad.idlocalidad) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.localidad != null ? !this.localidad.equals(localidad.localidad) : localidad.localidad != null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 89 * hash + (this.localidad != null ? this.localidad.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 89 * hash + this.idlocalidad;
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Cargo los datos del formulario.

```
private void cargarDatos() {
    obtener(idModificado);
    cliente.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
    cliente.setApellido(txtApellido.getText());
    cliente.setDomicilio(txtDomicilio.getText());
    cliente.setTelefono(txtTelefono.getText());
    cliente.setFacebook(txtFacebook.getText());
    cliente.setIdlocalidad(Integer.parseInt(cboLocalidad.getSelectedItem().toString()));
}
```

El método obtener()

```
public void obtener(int idCli) {
        try {
            DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerCliente = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_cliente(?)");
            obtenerCliente.setInt(1, idCli);
            obtenerCliente.execute();
            ResultSet rs = obtenerCliente.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                jtxtId.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("idcliente")));
                txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
                txtApellido.setText(rs.getString("apellido"));
                txtDomicilio.setText(rs.getString("domicilio"));
                txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("telefono"));
                txtFacebook.setText(rs.getString("facebook"));

                cboLocalidad.setSelectedItem(rs.getInt("idlocalidad"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener el cliente:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Que es el encargado de ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado de MySQL, el cual es:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `obtener_cliente`(IN id int)
SELECT idcliente, 
            nombre, 
            apellido, 
            domicilio, 
            telefono, 
            facebook, 
            idlocalidad
    FROM   Cliente
    WHERE  idcliente= id
```

Al cargar el formulario con todos los campos correspondiente el JComboBox se muestra asi.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me haya echo entender. Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución fue instanciar la clase `Localidad` dentro del método **obtener()** trabajando con la misma clase pasandole el objet y el string de dicho constructor de la misma. Tuve que crear un modelo con la clase `DefaultComboBoxModel` y añadir los elementos. El cual quedaría de la siguiente forma.

```
public void obtener(int idCli) {
    try {
        DefaultComboBoxModel valor = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
        CallableStatement obtenerCliente = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_cliente(?)");
        obtenerCliente.setInt(1, idCli);
        obtenerCliente.execute();
        ResultSet rs = obtenerCliente.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            jtxtId.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("idcliente")));
            txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            txtApellido.setText(rs.getString("apellido"));
            txtDomicilio.setText(rs.getString("domicilio"));
            txtTelefono.setText(rs.getString("telefono"));
            txtFacebook.setText(rs.getString("facebook"));
            //Instanciamos la clase Localidad y le asignamos con rs el campo idlocalidad y localidad.
            valor.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("idlocalidad"), rs.getString("localidad")));
            cboLocalidad.setModel(valor);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar obtener el cliente:\n"
                + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

En mi BD de datos modifique el procedimiento almacenado el cual agregue el campo "localidad" para que pueda pasarle por parametros la localidad al constructor de la clase `Localidad` el cual quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT idcliente, 
            nombre, 
            apellido, 
            domicilio, 
            telefono, 
            facebook, 
            C.idlocalidad,
            L.localidad
    FROM   Cliente C LEFT OUTER JOIN localidades L
    ON      C.idlocalidad = L.idlocalidad
    WHERE  idcliente= id
```

También realice una unión con la tabla localidades de mi BD.

En mi metodo **cargarDatos()** quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
private void cargarDatos() {
        obtener(idModificado);
        cliente.setNombre(txtNombre.getText());
        cliente.setApellido(txtApellido.getText());
        cliente.setDomicilio(txtDomicilio.getText());
        cliente.setTelefono(txtTelefono.getText());
        cliente.setFacebook(txtFacebook.getText());
        Localidad cbo = (Localidad) cboLocalidad.getSelectedItem();
        int id = cbo.getIdlocalidad();
        cliente.setIdlocalidad(id);
    }
```

**El resultado es:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]